# Padding in mobile view in css using div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple html page with some text and css, on the top I have a few imagens with slideshow and on the body I put a big text, but I'm learning html and css.

The Question:

I used padding for the text but when is mobile the padding is not good for reading, if someone can help me just take a look at the codes, I used w3schools as a reference to create the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
  div .padding {
    padding: 90px;
  }
</style>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}
  body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
  .mySlides {display: none;}
  img {vertical-align: middle;}

  /* Slideshow container */
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }

  /* Caption text */
  .text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
  .numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }

  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
  .dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }

  .active {
    background-color: #717171;
  }

  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
  }

  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
  }

  /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .text {font-size: 11px}
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.dooca.store/568/files/2img.jpg?v=1617815220" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Óleos Ozonizados</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.dooca.store/568/files/1img.jpg?v=1617815212" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Óleo de Girassol</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.dooca.store/568/files/3img.jpg?v=1617818739" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Óleo de Oliva</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

<div class="padding">
<p><strong>O que são os óleos ozonizados?</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: justify;">Os óleos ozonizados são produzidos basicamente a partir de 2 ingredientes, o óleo vegetal e o gás ozônio. A incorporação da molécula de ozônio ao óleo vegetal resulta de uma reação química, onde o ozônio reage com as ligações duplas de carbono presente nas cadeias lipídicas. Essa reação produz uma série de novas moléculas como ozonídeos e peróxidos que são responsáveis pela ação antimicrobiana e bioestimuladora dos óleos ozonizados. </p> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this:

```
  div .padding {
    padding: 90px;
  }
```

to

```
  .padding {
    padding: 90px;
  }
```

You should also only use one `<style>` tag.

Also would like to advice to check out Media Queries where you can control the styling base on Responsive:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries